# Do we care about the distance between quantum observables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables

In quantum mechanics, we care about the spectrum of quantum observable, the eigenvalues of observables, as  they give the measurement results. I wonder  if we have to care about the "distance" between quantum observables? Like, if we wanted to approximate an operator,  do we have to consider how close the approximate operator and the real operator are? Is my concern  sensible?

**Edit** My main question is: is there any need to know the distance between observable? By "need", I mean necessary in the theoretical derivation or computations; if you do not know the distance between operators, can you continue your work?

Comment: What do you mean by "have to care"? Sure, if you want to approximate some operator, you better be able to quantify *how close* that approximation is. But what exactly is the question about that?

Comment: Do you know how to compare two matrices?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Depends on what we needed. We can compare them by norm, the question is that will we need to.

Comment: In approximating operators, you normally use the norm. Read up on *Quantum Mechanics in Hilbert Space: 2nd Edition (Dover Books on Physics)*, by Eduard Prugovecki .

Comment: @CosmasZachos Can you tell me which chapter discusses that?

Comment: 4.1, convergence in norm and definition of Banach spaces; then, Ch 5; but the whole book and its methods and applications is based on the metric properties outlined there. The book is exceptionally sensible; a more rigorous, less seat-of-the-pants treatment of what you "learn in the street" of standard QM introductions...

Comment: If you prepare two particles by perfectly correlating their trajectories then you would need to place analyzers at equal distances to properly test them but the distance between them is not important.